# Select * from showing blank in PSQL shell after changing data type to binary

Tags: postgresql, elixir, ecto

I'm using Ecto/Elixir with Postgres and I created a field with the binary datatype. Everything is working OK except that now when I make a simple query: `Select * from "table name";` the sql shell shows only blank and seems that didn't like it...
What should I do to see these contents?

Comment: Possibly you're looking at large fieds with an alignment effect. In psql, try `\pset format unaligned` or the shortcut `\a`

Comment: @DanielVérité. That's it! Don't you want to turn this into an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `psql` display contents in cells aligned inside a grid. Each column is made wide enough to accodomate the largest value in it, and the smaller contents get blank-padded. When a column is much wider than the size of its containing window, entire pages of contents appear to be blank because of all the padding inside giant column(s) and the wrapping across consecutive lines.

The simplest workaround against that is to turn off alignement, with
`\pset format unaligned` or the on/off shortcut `\a`

Sometimes it's also interesting to use horizontal scrolling. Personally I use `less` as a pager with `LESS=-FX` as options and occasionally run inside `psql`:

```
\setenv LESS -FXS
```

then when displaying a result larger than the window, it does not wrap horizontally and the left and right cursor keys allow to scroll horizontally.

Also even when not using `-S` and when horizontal wrapping occurs, it's still possible with `less` to switch  to horizontal scrolling/paging by hitting the right cursor key <kbd>→</kbd> or <kbd>ESC</kbd><kbd>)</kbd> :

> ESC-) or RIGHTARROW
>          Scroll horizontally right N characters, default half the screen width  (see  the  -#
>          option).   If  a number N is specified, it becomes the default for future RIGHTARROW
>          and LEFTARROW commands.  While the text is scrolled, it acts as though the -S option
>          (chop lines) were in effect.